# How to use ICriteria with Enum properties in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, search, enums, criteria

Hi I want to write a FindByExample(object o) method.  So I tried this:

```
public IList<T> FindByExample(T o)
{
    return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(Example.Create(o)).List<T>();
}
```

(It's in a generic class)

It should work fine, but if T has a property of an enum type, it throws this exception:
"Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: EnumProperty expected type System.Int32, actual type EnumType"

The mapping is this:

`<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" ...>`

`<class name="OrdenDeCompra" table="ordenDeCompra" lazy="false">`

```
<id name="Id" column="id_ordenDeCompra" type="Int32">
  <generator class="increment" />
</id>

...

<property name="EnumType" column="id_enum" 
          type="Int32" not-null="true" />
...
```

`</class>`
 `</hibernate-mapping>`

How do I do search by Enum?

Answer (score 8):

Change the type of the map for the enum from Int32 to the type of the enum.

```
<property name="EnumType" column="id_enum" 
          type="namespace.here.enumTypeName, assemblyname" not-null="true" />
```

Edit:
The integer value of the enum will still be stored in the DB as an int though.