# How to setup a column that is an enumeration with Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

using nhibernate, how would I setup a column to be an enumeration type?

e.g.

User class has UserType which is an enumeration

```
public enum UserType { Normal = 1, Super = 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't build a map for the enum. You add the enum to a map on an object. Declare the type as the type of the enum. The column in the db needs to be an int, and NHib will map it properly.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889884/how-to-use-icriteria-with-enum-properties-in-nhibernate) in my answer.